# Wordpress use theme button and add php POST data

Tags: php, wordpress, button

I have a Wordpress site with Avada theme using Fusion Builder. I've added a button using Fusion Builder and there is a list of settings for that button, e.g. color, url, alignment etc. Currently i've set the url to load "page.php". So if the user clicks on it, they are taken to"page.php".
But I also have a  dropdown next to the button, and i want to POST the  selected e.g. Australia
Since the button has been built for me I dont know how to add the POST variables to the url so i can get something like:
page.php?selected_option="Australia"

i.e. how do i edit the button HTML and script?

Along with "url, color and alignment" there is another button option "give id to wrapping element". I've put "my_search_button". Now the page source is showing this: 
`<a id="my_search_button" ...><span class='fusion_button_text">Search</span></a>`. However for what I'm trying to do this doesn't seem like good practice

Comment: Unclear question. please explain properly that what you want to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check Proper Documentation for it all answers are in it

https://theme-fusion.com/support/documentation/avada-documentation/